# Canvas requestAnimationFrame pause

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How to pause canvas animation made with requestAnimationFrame ? 
I start animation like this:

Code:

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
    return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
            function(callback) {
                window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
            };
})();

function Start() {
    Update();
    requestAnimFrame(Start);
}

Start();
```

Now I want to add pause option after keydown. Is there any simple way to do it?

Comment: Ivan Chub solution works but the browser will continue calling the requestAnimationFrame callback. To avoid this behavior use [cancelAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.cancelAnimationFrame) instead. Consider see the requestAnimationFrame robust polyfill published [in this article](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/).

Comment: Shouldn't `requestAnimationFrame` be called in `Update()`? Otherwise you call a function that does nothing other than call another function.

Comment: what does the Update() function do? the question was not really answered here. Is there something special about that function we should know about?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you could do is create a variable that stores the state of your animation: paused or unpaused. Change that state every time you click a button. Something like this should work:

```
var isPaused = false;

window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
    return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
            function(callback) {
                window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
            };
})();

function Start() {
    if (isPaused) {
        Update();
    }

    requestAnimFrame(Start);
}

window.onkeydown = function() {
    isPaused = !isPaused; // flips the pause state
};

Start();
```