# requestAnimationFrame calling itself recursively, how is it possible to trigger end of animation event once?

Tags: javascript, recursion, requestanimationframe

I'm trying to perform same animation repeatedly one after another.
Here is requestAnimationFrame wrapper function and interval processing function:

```
Animator.prototype.animationFrame = function (options) {
    var requestAnimFrame =  requestAnimationFrame ||
                        webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                        mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                        msRequestAnimationFrame ||
                        function (callback) {return setTimeout(callback, 1000/60);},
        cancelAnimFrame = cancelAnimationFrame || mozCancelAnimationFrame,
        start = performance.now();

    var interval = requestAnimFrame(function animate(time) {

        var timeFraction = (time - start) / options.duration;
        if (timeFraction > 1) timeFraction = 1;

        var progress = options.timing(timeFraction);

        options.draw(progress);

        if (timeFraction < 1) {
            requestAnimFrame(animate);
        }else{
            cancelAnimFrame(interval);
            return options.callback();
        }
    });};
```

Callback function is calling in all recursive calls of animation and my goal is to trigger callback only once after what restart animation again.

Invocation of animation is going to be like this:

```
this.animationFrame({
        duration: 3000,
        timing: function linear(timeFraction) {
            return timeFraction;
        },
        draw: function(progress) {
            var result = to * progress;
            element.innerText = text.substr(0, Math.ceil(result))
        },
        callback: function () {
            self.clearStyles(self._wrapper);
            setTimeout(function () {
                self.startAnimations();
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
```

If working example needed I will provide it by the request. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I find this a little unclear. Typically the answer to this question more generally would be that you simply don't call the recursion after you want the loop to end. If you don't want the loop to end, but you do want to call the callback only once, then you'd set a flag that say's you've already fired the callback.

Comment: The thing is that requestAnimationFrame works with other css transitions. And may start on 'transitionend' event. I am trying to fire same event in the end of animation and restart all sequence of animatios. What I get is that on each iteretion fires x*2 events.

Comment: I have figured out solution using approach from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16555000/8944021 Not perfect, but works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have used flag `self.frameAnimationActive` to specify if animation frame need to be called. And the source of problem was that in my case `animationFrame()` is calling on `transitionend` witch fires on every property that is transitioned. That is why I have got multiple `animationFrame()` calls.

```
Animator.prototype.animationFrame = function (options) {
  var requestAnimFrame =  requestAnimationFrame ||
                          webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                          mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                          msRequestAnimationFrame ||
                          function (callback) {return setTimeout(callback, 1000/60);},
      self = this;
      self.frameAnimationActive = true;
      self.frameStart = performance.now();


  var mainFunction = function (params) {
      var timeFraction = (params.time - self.frameStart) / options.duration;

      if (timeFraction >= 1){
          if (self.frameAnimationActive) self.adUnit._trigger(new Event('textTypeFinished'));
          self.frameAnimationActive = false;
          timeFraction = 0;
          self.frameStart = params.time;
          options.callback();
      }

      if(self.frameAnimationActive){
          var progress = options.timing(timeFraction);

          options.draw(progress);

          requestAnimFrame(function (time) {
              params.time = time;
              return mainFunction.call(this, params);
          });
      }
  };
  mainFunction({time: performance.now()});
};
```